# UILocalNotification Maximum Discrepancy

Tags: ios, ios4, uilocalnotification, localnotification

In Apple's *Local and Push Notification Programming Guide*, it says:

> Each application on a device is
>   limited to the soonest-firing **64
>   scheduled local notifications**. The
>   operating system discards
>   notifications that exceed this limit.
>   It considers a recurring notification
>   to be a single notification. [**LINK**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW9)

However, in the *iOS Application Programming Guide*, it says

> Listing 4-3 shows an example that
>   schedules a single alarm using a date
>   and time that is set by the user. This
>   example configures only one alarm at a
>   time and cancels the previous alarm
>   before scheduling a new one. (Your own
>   applications can have **no more than 128
>   local notifications** active at any
>   given time, any of which can be
>   configured to repeat at a specified
>   interval.) [**LINK**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW13)

Which of these is true? Do I get 64 notifications or 128 notifications?

Comment: Churn out notifications one by one and see :P

Comment: Going by the modified date, 128. Probably would end up depending on the OS version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally did a test, and the answer is 64 local notifications.